# Determines the values of $a$ and $b$ so that $\alpha = 1$ is a root of multiplicity > 1

Tags: polynomials, roots

I have the polynomial $f(x) = ax^{n+1} + bx^n + 1 \in \Bbb Q[x]$ with $n \geq 1$

So the first thing I did was derive $f(x)$:

$f'(x) = (n+1)x^na + nbx^{n-1} + 0$ , and then evaluate with 1:

$f'(1) = (n+1)a(1)^n + nb(1)^{n-1} = (n+1)a + nb = 0$, now I think the next step is find a and b. Am I doing well?. What do I have to do for $\alpha = 1$ to be a root of multiplicity greater than one?

Comment: $1$ has to be a root, so $f(1)=0$.  That gives a second equation in $a,b$

Comment: For a smooth function, a root $\alpha$ of multiplicity $m$ means $f(\alpha)=0$,…, $f^{(m-1)}(\alpha)=0$, $f^{(m)}(\alpha)\neq 0$.

Comment: The [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4219959/roots-and-multiplicity-in-polynomials#comment8761412_4219959) under your previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4219959/roots-and-multiplicity-in-polynomials) answers this one as well.