# Root multiplicity.

Tags: polynomials, roots

Let $f(x)=ax^{n+1}+bx^n+1$ be a polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, $n\geq 1$. Determine the values $a$, and $b$ so that $\alpha =1$ is a root of multiplicity greater than 1.

I have an issue here. First I got the derivative, $f'(x)=a(n+1)x^n+bnx^{n-1}$. Then I replaced by 1 since it is a root, this is $f(1)=a+b+1=0$ and $f'(1)=a(n+1)+bn$.

From here I think is to clear $a$ and $b$ from an equation systeme. The thing is I don't know how to prove these values makes $f(x)=(x-1)^mq(x)$, with $q(x) \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $m\geq 2$

Comment: If $1$ is a root of $f$ and $f'$, then it is a root of $f$ with multiplicity $\geq 2$. You could assume by way of contradiction that $m=1$ and use the product rule.

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna try, many thanks!

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4220047 ?

Comment: Yeah, I think so. I didn't notice
Srry

Comment: Maybe you and Roy (from that earlier question) ought to form a study group. Two heads are better than one.